# Defining table compound primary keys in rails for Cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cequel

Given the following pseudo-cql table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE searches (
  category text, 
  timestamp timestamp, 
  no_of_searches int, 
  avg_searches double, 
  PRIMARY KEY((category, timestamp), no_of_searches)
);
```

and the following Rails Cequel model:

```
class Search
  include Cequel::Record

  # Table columns
  key :category,        :text
  key :timestamp,       :timestamp 
  key :no_of_searches,  :int
  column :avg_searches, :double
end
```

when I try to synchronise the model using:

```
rake cequel:migrate
```

the following rake error is thrown:

```
rake aborted!
Cequel::InvalidSchemaMigration: Existing partition keys category,timestamp differ from specified partition keys timestamp
```

I'm trying to get the above rails model to synchronise with the above table using the partition keys, although it's stating that the two sets of keys are different. I've tried defining the keys in the same order, but has not worked.

My objective is to get the pre-defined database table with partition keys working with the rails model. Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `key` method supports an options hash as a third parameter. The options hash adds further support to the defined key such as `order` and `partitioning`.

Based upon the given table definition it would mean your table columns would look something like this:

```
# Table columns
key :category,        :text,      { partition: true }
key :timestamp,       :timestamp, { partition: true }
key :no_of_searches,  :int
column :avg_searches, :double
```

Unfortunately this is not documented within the Cequel README, however it is documented within the code, for which can be found [here](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/1ec29b13f603c00d2dffdf8502be16a6b8d1cb65/lib/cequel/record/properties.rb#L81).